# Nonparallel Odds Regression Model in VGAM-Ordinal Response

Tags: multiple-regression, ordered-logit

I'm reading *Faraway's Extending the Linear Model with `R`* to brush up on ordinal multinomial regression.

I am considering data where there response is assumed to have a multinomial distribution where there are $k=4$ ordered levels. This is not as an extension of a Bernoulli where $k>2$ (that is the situation where $n=1$...I think Wikipedia calls this a categorical distribution), but instead I have counts for each of the $k$ levels summing to a total size $n$, e.g. a possible response vector would be $y_i=(2,3,1,3)$, where $y_{i1}=2, y_{i2}=3, y_{i3}=1, y_{i4}=3$ with $n=9$. My interest is not classification but estimation of $p_{ij}$.

I came across this generalization of the proportional odds model, where $\lambda_j(x)=P(Y\le j|x)$

[image]

To understand this, I imagined for a second that my response had the so-called categorical distribution (i.e. $n=1$) so that an example response vector could be of the form $(0,0,0,1)$. In the case you have four categories for example, how is this any different than fitting 3 different logistic models? 1st binary:(level 1 vs. (levels 2,3,4)); 2nd binary: (levels 1,2 vs levels 3,4); 3rd binary: (levels(1,2,3) vs. level 4). Going back to my data, does this extend to $n>1$ case, that is 1st binomial: (counts in level 1 vs counts in level 2,3,4) etc.

I ask because I fit

`vglm(cbind(counts1,counts2,counts3,counts4)~predictors,family = cumulative(parallel = FALSE),data=df)`

and compared with the respective coefficients

`glm(cbind(counts1,ntotal-counts1)~predictors,family="binomial",data=df)`

`glm(cbind(counts1+counts2,ntotal-counts1-counts2)~predictors,family="binomial",data=df)`

`glm(cbind(counts1+counts2+counts3,ntotal-counts1-counts2-counts3)~predictors,family="binomial",data=df)`

the corresponding non-intercept coefficients were almost the same (all within .1 of each other), while the intercepts for each level were a bit more substantially different (within .6 of each other).

Is there a reason for this? Is it how the coefficients are estimated? Is it how the estimates are calculated with respect to the package? Was the closeness of the non-intercept coefficients coincidental?

NOTE: The vector $ntotal$ is not constant; that is the number of total counts varies from observation to observation...I wonder whether that complicates things?